# dart:js calling a javascript function

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm building an app with AngularDart and need to use a Leaflet plugin that is not yet available in Dart (AwesomeMarkers).

I have imported `dart:js` as `JS`. Here is the code:

```
JS.JsFunction icon = JS.context["L"]["AwesomeMarkers"]["icon"];
Map args = {"icon" : name, "markerColor" : color, "prefix" : "fa"};
return icon.apply([new JS.JsObject.jsify(args)]);
```

The debugger shows that the function `icon` is well defined and captured in the JsFunction, but when calling `apply`, I get this error:

`EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'JsObject' has no instance getter '_icon'.
Receiver: Instance of 'JsObject'
Tried calling: _icon`

I've tried many things, but none seem to work.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment of Günter Zöchbauer, I've abandoned the idea of using `dart:js` and used `package:js` instead. It works way better but takes some time to put in place.

For those who are interested in using Leaflet with dart, here is a [link](https://github.com/arthurdeschamps/kapua-iot-gateway-simulation/blob/develop/webapp-angular/lib/src/sections/map/interop/Leaflet.interop.dart) to a very basic interoperability file, and [here](https://github.com/arthurdeschamps/kapua-iot-gateway-simulation/blob/develop/webapp-angular/lib/src/sections/map/interop/LeafletAwesomeMarkers.interop.dart) another one for AwesomeMarkers.

Comment: Is this only in Dartium or also in Chrome? I'd suggest using `package:js` instead of `dart:js` https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js for Dart-js-interop.

Comment: I have only tried in Dartium for now. Should I try in Chrome ? I'm going to check `package:js`, thank you.

Comment: For trying in chrome just copy the URL from the Dartium tab to a Chrome tab and wait a bit until `pub serve` is done building JS.

Comment: Ok, so in Chrome I get this error:
`NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'get$_icon' (t2.get$_icon is not a function)`.
I'm trying to use `package:js/js.dart` but it seems to conflict with `dart:js` but its probably realted to WebStorm.

Comment: I have just realised the error is not in those lines. I'm very sorry for that. Actually it comes from another Dart object that tries to use the JsObject.